# How to show Material Calendar with all disabled dates in Android datePickerDialog

Tags: android, material-components-android, datepickerdialog

I am trying to make a calendar date picker dialog pop-up with a condition. User selects month and year at first. Hence, `DatePickerDialog` pop-up will show with minimum 28 days (for `February` only) and maximum 31days (for `January`, `March`, `May, …, December`). User is able to pick particular date in a previously selected month of the year. 
 Thus, those dates on which user gave attendance are set enabled, rest dates are set disabled.
 Now, there may be a situation that user was absent for the whole month. I want to show all the dates set disabled in the calendar for that particular month of the year. I was looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#datepickerdialog-setselectabledayscalendar-days) that there were methods called `setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)` and `setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)`, both takes `@NonNull` array of calendar objects to enable and disable dates repectively.

So, for this case if there was no attendance date for a particular month, I tried to make a `absentDates` array of calendar and passed it to the second method i.e. `setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)`. But, it not showing anything. I tried and checked that except one day in a specific month, I can disable rest days, not all the dates at once (an image is attached of that). I want all the dates disabled in the `DatePickerDialog` pop-up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the official `MaterialDatePicker` you can implement your own `DateValidator` to enable/disable days and setting it to the `CalendarConstraints` object before building the dialog with `MaterialDatePicker.Builder().datePicker().setCalendarConstraints(contraints)`

You can find a sample implementation here for [DateValidatorPointForward](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/69e484dd1eaa1200da54c8a8b8fc505969703f37/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/DateValidatorPointForward.java).

Documentation: https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#using-date-pickers